How to surpass this undefined read on Paypal's generated page on React
I am using PayPal sandbox to play with the payment method.
I have an order component that has the configuration for the button render. I have created a script tag on index.html with my client's ID too.
This is the code inside the order component that has the config for the button and the button that takes you to PayPal's popup window.
const paypal = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
    window.paypal
    .Buttons({
      createOrder: (data, actions, err) => {
        return actions.order.create({
          intent: "CAPTURE",
          purchase_units: [
            {
              description: "Cool looking table",
              amount: {
                currency_code: "USD",
                value: 650.0,
              },
            },
          ],
        });
      },
      onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
        const order = await actions.order.capture();
        console.log(order);
      },
      onError: (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      },
    })
    .render(paypal.current);
}, [])
return(
.
.
.
<div ref={paypal}></div>
...)

On the PayPal popup window, I manage to successfully login then very briefly get the pay button before it abruptly goes away and then I get this message.
"We are unable to process your payments using your PayPal account at this time. Please return to the merchant and try to use another payment method."
After inspecting elements, it seems there is an error on the popup window where PayPal is creating a script tag that adds an event listener on an element that doesn't exist and it's returning an undefined error.
<script nonce>
if ('undefined') {
document.getElementById('cancelLink').addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.close()
})

}

Not directly related to your problem, but actions.order.create( and actions.order.capture( are deprecated functions. PayPal has begun sending communications that they will be sunset and processing switched off, do not use them. Instead, create and capture orders from a secured server with the v2/checkout/orders API (or using the native SDK) The react frontend can stay as it is other than making use of such routes. See the standard integration guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/
